# WatiN Error : could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, watin

I am working on a new test project with `watiN`,

I downloaded WatiN (Web application test in `.Net`) tools and wanted to run the web test using Visual Studio `.Net` 2010

but always get this error,

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'WatiN.Core, Version=2.1.0.1196,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or one of its dependencies.
 The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Did I miss something? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try: Right click on reference, Properties, Set "Copy local" to "True"

Comment: Thanks : t3hn00b For reply. I have try it but it is not working. Have a any other solution??